# qTip2 prevents clicks on underlaying elements

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am using qTip2 to show a help message near the mouse cursor.

```
 position: {
   target: 'mouse'
 }
```

But I cannot click on anything because qTip is always under the mouse, it prevents from clicking anything under it. How can I move the tip some pixels aside from mouse (so it still follows it)?

http://jsfiddle.net/7LDmA/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code do your CSS

It will position the element 10 pixels lower:

```
#qtip-0 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hKHAk/

Comment: When the tooltip is positionned at the top, for example if the viewport position is active, the tooltip will be moved even more under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You may let the pointer click through the tooltip:

```
#qtip-0 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```